# Webpack changing file in script tag

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-boilerplate

I'm new to ReactJS and Webpack, I'm using react-boilerplate and I am trying to add a template to the boilerplate which has it's own set of external libraries.

Problem that I'm facing is every time I am trying to include a  tag that links to these external libraries, webpack re-compiles these files and changes the content. This is throwing an error.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- The first thing in any HTML file should be the charset -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- Make the page mobile compatible -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Allow installing the app to the homescreen -->
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <title>Avalon</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/scripts/core/libraries/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- The app hooks into this div -->
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

At runtime, if I check the source of **jquery.min.js** it's content is changed.

I'm not sure what to change in the configuration, or what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Why not just import `jquery` in your main js file and attach it to the `window` object if you need it globally? It would be much cleaner than checking in a library with your source

Comment: for jquery I had thought of that, but there is an entire external bundles folder which I need to import without having it compiled by webpack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include external libraries as it is with webpack output, the [`external`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html) configuration might help you.

Your custom library might look like,

```
var jQuery = require("jquery");

function YourLib() {}

// ...

module.exports = YourLib;
```

Then the config to expose your library would be

```
{
    output: {
    // export itself to a global var
    libraryTarget: "var",
    // name of the global var: "YourLib"
    library: "YourLib"
},
    externals: {
        // require("jquery") is external and available
        //  on the global var jQuery
        "jquery": "jQuery"
    }
}
```

This will not include the `jquery` library in webpack output but the custom library `YourLib` would be included in the bundle which `require`s `jQuery` which is included as `script` tag.

Comment: will try this, what if the library to be included is a custom library not published as an npm module ? for eg: can we give the path to the file instead of using require in externals ?